# Changing default font in GRUB2 - 'Unknown gsub font feature'

Tags: grub2, fonts, ubuntu-font-family

I wanted to change a default GRUB2 because it's to small for me. I downloaded [ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/) and tried to convert it to `*.pf2`:

`grub-mkfont -s -16 --range=0x0-0x7f -o ./ubufont.pf2  ubuntufont.ttf`

but it showed some 'errors' and font wasn't created:

```
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x63617365 (case)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x646e6f6d (dnom)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x66726163 (frac)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6c6f636c (locl)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6e756d72 (numr)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x6f72646e (ordn)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x706e756d (pnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73616c74 (salt)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73616c74 (salt)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73696e66 (sinf)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73733031 (ss01)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73733031 (ss01)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73756273 (subs)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x73757073 (sups)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
Unknown gsub font feature gsub 0x746e756d (tnum)
```

So how can I change default GRUB2 font to Ubuntu font? Cheers

Comment: I know this question is ~5 years old but I see you signed on last month. Did you ever solve this problem? (Sorry about your lost to Croatia today but happy for a tiny country like that to be in the spotlight).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I prefer **Grub Customizer**. Safe and clear usage.

First [check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Tnt95FsBNhU#t=200).

**Installation via terminal**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont really like Grub Customizer. But thought - 'Ok, maybe this time it will work' and installed in on my Virtualbox Ubuntu. Changed font (did ONLY that), restarted Ubuntu. Now I cant even run my Ubuntu on Virtualbox, can't see GRUB, only black screen :d That's why I don't like Grub Customizer ... I like to know what exactly I have to do with my OS, even if it will be a little more difficult. Anyway - thanks

Comment: So strange. I'm using it since 10.10 and I noticed only one problem what appears when you use a non-unicode font. I understood your opinion anyway.